# Are Jews allowed to wear clothing made from dyes from nonkosher animals or bugs?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, clothing, bugs, color

If a garment is dyed using dye from bugs, is that kosher?

Comment: murex trunculus has entered the chat

Comment: Exceptio non probat regulam

Comment: It's not the only example, just the one that probably most readily comes to mind for most folks... aside from the hilazon there is also the tolaath shani. There is no prohibition against using dyes made from non-kosher animals (nor against using products from non-kosher animals generally, such as pigskin on a football).

Comment: Teffilin dye .....

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Silk is permissible, right?  If the actual item of clothing can be made from a non-kosher worm, what added element would the dye bring? I heard this comes up in some people's argument about tekheleth. And that's not my lane :)

Answer (score 6):

The prohibition against eating bugs does not include deriving benefit from them.

Similarly, leather from non-kosher animals can be used for clothing.

The Rambam ([משנה תורה, הלכות מאכלות אסורות ח׳](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Foods.8.15?lang=bi)) codifies this as follows:

> כָּל מָקוֹם שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר בַּתּוֹרָה לֹא תֹאכַל לֹא תֹאכְלוּ לֹא יֹאכְלוּ לֹא יֵאָכֵל אֶחָד אִסּוּר אֲכִילָה וְאֶחָד אִסּוּר הֲנָאָה בְּמַשְׁמָע עַד שֶׁיִּפְרֹט לְךָ הַכָּתוּב כְּדֶרֶךְ שֶׁפֵּרֵט לְךָ בִּנְבֵלָה שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (דברים יד כא) "לַגֵּר אֲשֶׁר בִּשְׁעָרֶיךָ תִּתְּנֶנָּה וַאֲכָלָהּ" וְכַחֵלֶב שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר בּוֹ (ויקרא ז כד) "יֵעָשֶׂה לְכָל מְלָאכָה". אוֹ עַד שֶׁיִּתְפָּרֵשׁ בַּתּוֹרָה שֶׁבְּעַל פֶּה שֶׁהוּא מֻתָּר בַּהֲנָאָה. כְּגוֹן שְׁקָצִים וּרְמָשִׂים וְדָם וְאֵיבָר מִן הַחַי וְגִיד הַנָּשֶׁה. שֶׁכָּל אֵלּוּ מֻתָּרִין בַּהֲנָאָה מִפִּי הַקַּבָּלָה אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהֵן אֲסוּרִין בַּאֲכִילָה:‏

> Wherever the Torah states: "Do not eat," "You shall not eat," "They shall not eat," or "It shall not be eaten," the intent is that it is forbidden both to partake of or benefit from the forbidden entity unless:
> a) a verse explicitly states otherwise, as it does with regard to a nevelah (dead animals)[Deuteronomy 14:21]: "Give it to the stranger in your gate and he shall partake of it," or with regard to forbidden fat [Leviticus 7:24]: "You may use it for any task"; or
> b) the Oral Law states explicitly that it is permitted to benefit from it, as is the case with regards to bugs, worms, blood, a limb from a living animal, and the gid hanesheh - the sciatic nerve. For according to the Oral Tradition, it is permitted to benefit from all these prohibited entities, even though it is forbidden to eat them.

Bottom line: a garment that is dyed using dye from bugs, is "kosher" and may be worn.

Comment: If the dye is made from orlah produce on the other hand...

Comment: Correct, as supported by the Rambam's rule.